# Speeding up Jquery/Json search

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

This is my first time working with javascript/jquery and I really had to go through this step by step but I finally have it working exactly like I would like. I have a JSON file that looks like this.

```
[
  {
    "Procedure Code":"G0101",
    "Par Fee":"$39.78 ",
    "Nonpar Fee":"$37.79 ",
    "Limiting Charge":"$43.46 "
  },
  {
    "Procedure Code":"G0101",
    "Par Fee":"$28.86 ",
    "Nonpar Fee":"$27.42 ",
    "Limiting Charge":"$31.53 "
  },
  {
    "Procedure Code":"G0102",
    "Par Fee":"$20.39 ",
    "Nonpar Fee":"$19.37 ",
    "Limiting Charge":"$22.28 "
  },
  {
    "Procedure Code":"G0102",
    "Par Fee":"$9.10 ",
    "Nonpar Fee":"$8.65 ",
    "Limiting Charge":"$9.95 "
  },
  {
    "Procedure Code":"G0104",
    "Par Fee":"$176.69 ",
    "Nonpar Fee":"$167.86 ",
    "Limiting Charge":"$193.04 "
  },
```

The user enters a Procedure code such as "G0101" and is presented with all the relevant info. I wanted the searching to be more a live type search. So currently the user is presented with just search box. As the user types once a match is found a formatted table appears with the results. If they were to start hitting backspace to search a different code the table disappears until a new match is found. All of this is working exactly as intended. However my problem is  all of my testing was done with a JSON file containing only around 10 different codes. Now that I was done I switched it to the full file, I don't know the exact number of entries but its 65,000 lines long. The searching is VERY slow now to the point its basically no longer usable. Like I said this is my first time working with Jquery and I don't know if its just the way I'm going about things and there is a proficient method or this is simply to much data to be looping through. I have read that maybe I should be using a for loop instead of.each witch will help with performance. I'm hoping someone can look through this and give some advice if there is a better way of doing this. Thanks for any suggestions.

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    $('#searchCode').keyup(function(){

        var usersCode = $('#searchCode').val();
        var usersCodeUpper = usersCode.toUpperCase();
        console.log(usersCodeUpper);
        console.log("test");

            $.ajax({

                url: 'http://westcotesting.dev/wp-content/themes/westcotest/data.json',
                datatype: 'json',
                type: 'get',
                cache: 'true',
                success: function(IDCresults){
                    $(IDCresults).each(function(index,value){

                        var pCode               = (value['Procedure Code'])
                        var parFee              = (value['Par Fee'])
                        var nonParFee           = (value['Nonpar Fee'])
                        var limitingCharge      = (value['Limiting Charge'])


                        if (usersCodeUpper == pCode) {

                            var pCodeH4             = "<h4>" + pCode + "</h4>"
                            var parFeeH4            = "<h4>" + parFee + "</h4>"
                            var nonParFeeH4         = "<h4>" + nonParFee + "</h4>"
                            var limitingChargeH4    = "<h4>" + limitingCharge + "</h4>"

                            $("div#code_results_wrapper").removeClass("no-js")
                            $("#codeResults").html(pCodeH4)
                            $("#parFeeResults").append(parFeeH4)
                            $("#nonParFeeResults").append(nonParFeeH4)
                            $("#limitingChargeResults").append(limitingChargeH4)

                    }
                        $('#searchCode').keyup(function(){

                            $("div#code_results_wrapper").addClass("no-js")
                            $("#parFeeResults").html(" ")
                            $("#nonParFeeResults").html(" ")
                            $("#limitingChargeResults").html(" ")
                        });                                             
                });
            }
        })
    });
 });
```

Comment: You're fetching the file on each keyup consider moving ajax outside and only do search in keyup.

Comment: Also to speed up the search you use binary search if you sort the array first.

Comment: @jcubic sorting that much content may be too expensive.

Answer (score 1):

1 - first of all as @jcubic told in comment, consider doing **less search operations** :

```
// nb of milliseconds before search operation
var searchDelay = 500
var searchTimeout;
$('#searchCode').keyup(function(){
    clearTimeout(searchTimeout);
    searchTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        // search logic here
    }, searchDelay);
});
```

2 - Consider using **`break` as soon as you find a result**:

```
for(/* some loop logic*/) {
    // some operations
    if (match) {
        // some operation when result found
        // ...
        break;
    }
}
```

3 - You may **change your JSON structure** for a better efficiency :

exemple of json (if procedures codes are unique) :

```
var json = {
  "G0101": {
    "Par Fee":"$39.78 ",
    "Nonpar Fee":"$37.79 ",
    "Limiting Charge":"$43.46 "
  },
  "G0101": {
    "Par Fee":"$28.86 ",
    "Nonpar Fee":"$27.42 ",
    "Limiting Charge":"$31.53 "
  },
  "G0102": {
    "Par Fee":"$20.39 ",
    "Nonpar Fee":"$19.37 ",
    "Limiting Charge":"$22.28 "
  },
  "G0102": {
    "Par Fee":"$9.10 ",
    "Nonpar Fee":"$8.65 ",
    "Limiting Charge":"$9.95 "
  },
  "G0104": {
    "Par Fee":"$176.69 ",
    "Nonpar Fee":"$167.86 ",
    "Limiting Charge":"$193.04 "
  }
}
```

You can use a `for..in` loop on the object keys :

```
for (var proc_code in json) {
    if (proc_code === search_text) {
        var details = json[proc_code];
        var limiting_charge = details["Limiting Charge"];
        // ...
        break;
    }
}
```

4 - **avoid downloading that json each time**

- download it once and perform search on it when needed
- only download a relevant set of partial match (server side: `if (entry.Contains(search_text)) { future_json.Add(entry) }`)

5 - consider using some **existing plugins** :

jQuery Tokeninput plugin let you send a search text server side (you have to implement the search process), download the results and display them in a dropdown list :

http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/

Hope this helps !